# Does Zurb Foundation 4 work with Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, zurb-foundation, ruby-on-rails-4

I've installed Foundation v4.1.6 on a test Rails 4rc1 project and it seems to work fine. But I want to install it on a production environment and I'd like to know if there are any major issues I just didn't see yet?

Comment: <crickets>  I'm curious too...

Comment: I haven't experienced any issues so far beyond issues with Foundation I'm pretty sure exist in Rails 3 as well.

Comment: yeah, I've been playing around with Foundation 4.x and Rails 4(rc2) for last day or so...and so far so good!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it works well. I don't use compass though, its not required.

There were a number of fixes to the foundation-rails gem which have not yet made it into a new release of the gem. I merged those fixes into my own fork so I could get things working smoothly with a Rails 4 project I am working on.

The details are in a related SO question I just answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20473318/2238268

Answer (score 3):

Yes now it can. I found different docs, here's how I've done it.

Gemfile

```
  gem 'compass-rails', github: "milgner/compass-rails", branch: "rails4"
  gem 'zurb-foundation'
```

Bash console

```
rails generate foundation:install
```

application.js

```
//= require foundation
```

application.css

```
*
*= require foundation
*/

@import "layout/*.png";
@include all-layout-sprites;
```

References:

- http://threetreeslight.com/post/51303399725/rails4-compass-rails

Comment: Also, if you don't feel like learning Japanese: https://gist.github.com/variousauthors/6142170