# Upgrading to Zurb Foundation 5 with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, zurb-foundation

I just switched from Foundation 4 to Foundation 5.  I don't know how or where to set the global styles variables.  In Foundation 4 the file `foundation_and_overrides.scss` provided all the global variables and all I had to do was uncomment them.  Now in Foundation 5 this same file does not contain any variables. I looked at the Global Styles documentation and there are listed all the global variables.  But when I try to put them into the `foundation_and_overrides.scss` file nothing changes.

Answer (score 4):

I created a fork of foundation-rails that merges in a number of important fixes/pull requests until they get integrated into master.  Its working well for me (ymmv).

My fork is available here: https://github.com/ahacking/foundation-rails

Just put in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'foundation-rails', github: 'ahacking/foundation-rails'
```

When those pull requests are merged into master and the gem is released you can revert back to the official gem.

I also copy the foundation 5 settings file to `app/assets/stylesheets/settings/_foundation.css.sccs` which allows me to modify settings I see fit.

I simply include it before foundation in application.css.scss as follows:

```
@import
  "config/_foundation",
  "foundation"
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update the "foundation-rails" gem to the latest version and do the foundation:install again. This behaviour is fixed in 5.0.2.0.

Comment: ok, I'm guessing I need to change the variable `$body-bg` inside `foundation_and_overrides.scss`, right?  Well changing it doesn't change the background-color of all my pages.